# neo4j indegree outdegree union

Tags: neo4j

I want to compute Indegree and Outdegree and return a graph that has a connection between top 5 Indegree nodes and top 5 Outdegree nodes. I have written a code as

```
match (a:Port1)<-[r]-()
return a.id as NodeIn, count(r) as Indegree
order by Indegree DESC LIMIT 5
union
match (n:Port1)-[r]->()
return n.id as NodeOut, count(r) as Outdegree
order by Outdegree DESC LIMIT 5
union
match p=(u:Port1)-[:LinkTo*1..]->(t:Port1)
where u.id in NodeIn and t.id in NodeOut 
return p
```

I get an error as

> All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names (line 4, column 1 (offset: 99)) "union"

What are the changes that I need to do to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things we can improve.

The matches you're doing isn't the most efficient way to get incoming and outgoing degrees for relationships.

Also, UNION can only be used to combine query results with identical columns. In this case, we won't even need UNION, we can use WITH to pipe results from one part of a query to another, and COLLECT() the nodes you need in between.

Try this query:

```
match (a:Port1)
with a, size((a)<--()) as Indegree
order by Indegree DESC LIMIT 5

with collect(a) as NodesIn
match (a:Port1)
with NodesIn, a, size((a)-->()) as Outdegree
order by Outdegree DESC LIMIT 5

with NodesIn, collect(a) as NodesOut
unwind NodesIn as NodeIn
unwind NodesOut as NodeOut
// we now have a cartesian product between both lists
match p=(NodeIn)-[:LinkTo*1..]->(NodeOut)
return p
```

Be aware that this performs two NodeLabelScans of :Port1 nodes, and does a cross product of the top 5 of each, so there are 25 variable length path matches, which can be expenses, as this generates all possible paths from each NodeIn to each NodeOut.

If you only one the shortest connection between each, then you might try replacing your variable length match with a shortestPath() call, which only returns the shortest path found between each two nodes:

```
...
match p = shortestPath((NodeIn)-[:LinkTo*1..]->(NodeOut))
return p
```

Also, make sure your desired direction is correct, as you're matching nodes with the highest in degree and getting an outgoing path to nodes with the highest out degree, that seems like it might be backwards to me, but you know your requirements best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It helps me a lot!. But, I didn't get one of your statement, "seems like backward". What do you mean by that? Do you mean that the requirement doesn't be a part of analysis or is of no value?

Comment: No, that thought is just based on how it's sometimes easy to mix up your direction, and how going from a node of high out degree to high in degree seems like it's going "with the current" and going in reverse (as in your query) is going against it. With absolutely no background into what you want, it seemed possible you might have mixed up the direction by mistake. But if the direction is as you intended, then all is well.